# How to declare React.Component type from external module with separate declaration file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Say, there is an external module that exported a React Component. That module doesn't have flow declaration. I want to declare it to enable flow type checking.

For example, that module is defined like this:

```
import React from 'react'

class External extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>
  }
}
```

If I wrote that my self (internal module) Flowtype will be able to detect missing
props. But, since that `External` component is exported from external module.
Flow doesn't do type checking. So, I need to create separate type declaration
for that module.

I tried this:

```
// ./interfaces/the-external-module.js.flow

declare module "the-external-module" {
  declare export var External: React.Component;
}
```

Of course it doesn't work because React is not within scope. So, how can I
declare that `External` as `React.Component` in separate type declaration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some of the [official definitions](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/f86b0822d6c58059e541745a3ebfc210c62baf37/definitions/npm/react-modal_v1.x.x/flow_%3E%3Dv0.26.x/react-modal_v1.x.x.js#L21), use `React$Component` (defined in the source [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/2600ed9b43d6b8af461d3713889e5c8d2cdbd069/lib/react.js#L16)); e.g.

```
declare module "the-external-module" {
  declare export var External: React$Component;
}
```

Comment: That works. But, before I accept the answer, could you give at least one example? It may helps future viewers.

Comment: Sure, I've added an example